# button is clicable when page start loading in v-if query

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have this code in Vue that's supposed to show one or another depending on if `listTesis` has elements or not. It works, but if you reload the page and you're fast clicking the button, it's allowing you to enter the first `router-link` even when you shouldn't.

```html
          <div class="card-tools">
            <template v-if="listTesis.length == 0">
              <router-link class="btn btn-info bnt-sm" :to="'/tesis/crear'">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i> Ingresar Formulario de inscripcion
              </router-link>
            </template>
            <template v-else>
              <router-link class="btn btn-info bnt-sm link-disabled" :to="''">
              <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i> Usted ya ingreso un formulario
              </router-link>
            </template>
          </div>
```

`listTesis` is  defined like this inside of `data`:

```
data() {
  return {
    ...
    listTesis:[],
  }
}
```

In `mounted`, I have the function call:

```
mounted() {
  this.getListarTesis();
},
```

In `methods`, I have the function

```
getListarTesis() {
  this.fullscreenLoading = true;
  var url = '/alumno/getListarTesis'
  axios.get(url, {
  }).then(response => {
      this.inicializarPaginacion();
      this.listTesis = response.data;
      this.fullscreenLoading = false;
  })
},
```

Everything works well, but if you're fast, while the page reload, you're able to click the button where you're not supposed to.

I tried using `beforeMount` instead of `mounted`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize `listTesis` to `null`, and use `v-if="listTesis"` on the `<div>` parent:

```html
<template>                        
  <div class="card-tools" v-if="listTesis">
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {      
      listTesis: null,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Since the `axios.get()` callback sets `listTesis` to a non-`null` value, both `<router-link>` elements are hidden until the `GET` request completes.